# Integrating triangle in a 2D plane

Tags: calculus, integration, triangles, surface-integrals

I am interested in integrating $(x^2y+y^2x)$ on the following loop: $(x=1,y=2)\rightarrow(x=2,y=1)\rightarrow(x=3,y=3)\rightarrow(x=1,y=2)$.

I know this loop forms a triangle with all three sides changing with respect to the $x$ and $y$ axis. I understand how to do the integration part, but unfortunately I am really stuck on how to set up the integration itself. Should I do a double integral for each side of the triangle and then add them?

If anyone can help me set up the integration for this problem it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done using two double integrals. Here you are dividing the triangle into two parts by the vertical line $x=2$.

The equation of the line joining $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ is $x+y=3$, and that of the line joining $(1,2)$ to $(3,3)$ is $x-2y+3=0$.

You can set $x=1$ to $x=2$, and then you will have the range of $y$ as $y=3-x$ to $y=\frac{x+3}{2}$.

The equation of the line joining $(2,1)$ to $(3,3)$ is $2x-y=3$.

Then you can set $x=2$ to $x=3$, and you will get the range of $y$ as $y=2x-3$ to $y=\frac{x+3}{2}$.

EDIT:

The question meant to ask integrating along the loop, not over the region bounded by it.

For each line, the curve can be parameterized. Example procedure for $y=3-x$.

Let $x=t$. Then, $y=3-t$. $t$ varies from $1$ to $2$.

The function $x^2y+y^2x$ then becomes $t^2(1-t)+t(1-t)^2$.

$$\oint {(x^2y+y^2x).dr}= \int_{1}^{2} {(t^2(1-t)+t(1-t)^2)|v(t)|dt}+otherterms$$.

where $$|v(t)|=\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2}=\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I found the slope and y intercept of all three lines, but I am not sure how to move forward with this information. What would my next step be?

Comment: @user131763 As the other answer says, parameterization may make things easy. If you wish to do this way, however, what can be done is divide the triangle in two parts by the line $x=2$. Then, from $x=1$ to $x=2$, the range of $y$ is from one side of the triangle to the other (equaitons in the answer), and for $x=2$ to $x=3$, $y$ ranges from another lower bound to the same upper bound. Thus you can set up two double integrals.

Comment: I like the direction hat your solution is leading me, if I were to take the equations for each line and use them to find a relationship between dx and dy would I be able to do three single integrals and then add them? For example, from (2,1) to (3,3) the equation is y=2x-3; so, for that part of the triangle,  would I be able to say dy=2dx and then integrate from 2 to 3 for [x^2(2x-3)dx+2(2x-3)^2x dx? and then do something similar for the other two sides and then add them in the end?

Comment: If the question in the text book is worded as "carry out the integration of x^2y+y^2x" do you think that means to integrate "along the lines" or "over the region", because now I am not sure what it is asking for.

Comment: "Carry out the integration of (x^2y+y^2x) on the following loop: (x=1,y=2)->(x=2,y=1)->(x=3,y=3)->(x=1,y=2)"

Comment: @user131763 It probably means the line integral then.

Comment: Okay, so I will follow the method you provided in your solution. Thank you so much for all of your help! I really appreciate all of the time you took to help me understand this problem!

Comment: @GoodDeeds Green theorem does not apply here, as we are integrating a scalar field, and not a vector field.

Comment: @Kuifje Just realized the major blunder. Very sorry, I removed that line. Hope the rest is fine? If not I will remove the answer. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can always parameterize a triangle with $u,v$, where $u,v>0$ and $u+v<1$. This always leads to an integral
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^u\ldots dv\,du$$

[Convex interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) inside the triangle with vertices A,B,C is then
$$T=Au+Bv+C(1-u-v)$$
Imagine that "u" is the variable that tells you how much you move from C to A, and "v" the same from C to B. (u=0,v=0) is now C, (u=1,v=0) is now A, and (u=0,v=1) is B. That defines your variable change for both coordinates.
For illustration, see sketches for [Barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) (we are integrating over two of barycentric coordinates, and the third one is expressed with the other two $1-u-v$).

From this you must also compute the Jacobian (which is the ratio how much your original triangle is bigger than the unit triangle (0,0)→(1,0)→(0,1) in (u,v) space where you are doing the integral).

In your case:

$$(x,y)=(u+2v+3(1-u-v),2u+v+3(1-u-v))=(3-2u-v,3-u-2v)$$
and the jacobian:

$$J=\det\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{bmatrix} =(-2)(-2)-(-1)(-1)=3$$

This leaves you with

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^u \left((3-2u-v)^2(3-u-2v)+(3-u-2v)^2(3-2u-v)\right) 3 dv\,du$$

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this answer is leaving me even more confused than I was before. Are you suggesting that I compute a double integral for each side of the triangle and then add them?

Comment: No, I just told you the transformation from your triangle to the "unit" triangle from (0,0)→(1,0)→(0,1)→(0,0) in variables u and v, which is trivially integrated (I wrote out the integral). No need to split into more triangles, just one integral is enough (and after this transformation, it's the same for every triangle in existence).

Comment: Okay, I read over your solution a few times and its starting to make more sense to me. The only question I have is where did you get the numbers you used to set up the jacobian. Jacobian always tends to confuse me so if you could elaborate a little more on that step I would be so grateful!

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! I understand how to go about this problem now and I really appreciate all of the time you spent to explain this solution to me!

Comment: I extended it. But Jacobian is easy to understand... it's the "stretch" of coordinates - when you change variables in single integrals, you take derivative and write dx=something*du. Here you have dx*dy=jacobian*du*dv - same thing.